# Protecting a post from being removed due to spam flags

Tags: support, spam

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359635/udp-server-and-client-in-delphi/4359645#4359645) has 5 spam flags (meaning that one more will delete the post), despite meeting all the criteria for self-promotion and being the highest voted answer for the question.

Is there some way for me to flag the post as not spam? (possibly flagging the post for moderator attention - are diamond mods able to reset the spam flag count?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you and have removed the flags on that answer. If people feel this needs more discussion, feel free to do that here.

There is currently no way for non-moderators to officially disagree with flags, but thoughts about something like that are happening.

Comment: I think that simply flagging it for moderation attention (to disagree with the flags, explaining why), and disabling the ability to flag as spam for questions that had their spam flags removed in the current revision should be enough.